Run smallest subset of tests which are probable to test currently changed code
I would like to run smaller subset of existing tests which are known to exercise (coverage) changed files. I would like to checkout codebase (using some VCS; like git). Than change some files and run tests, which does cover changed files.
I expect that code coverage from unchanged codebase is available.
I have not tried anything. I do not know any maven plugin, which would be able to do this.

"I have not tried anything" isn't going to help you get help. You could at least do some research.

Out of curiosity, what's the reason you can't just run all the tests? Are they too slow?
